# Junit Testing for Thread.sleep() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I wanted to write unit test cases for the function to test if the Thread.sleep() function is working.

Can someone please provide a piece of code which would help me achieve this task? :

```
public class A implements B {

 public int func(String A) throws ApplicationException {

    int ctr = 0;
    int ans = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<100020;i++) {
        try {
              ++ctr;
              if(ctr%50==0)
              {
                   try
                   {
                          Thead.sleep(1000);
                   }
                   catch(java.lang.InterruptedException ie)
                   {
                        System.out.println(ie);
                   }

              }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {

        } 
        finally {

        }
    }

    return ans;
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to look into Powermock? With powermock you can test and verify static methods - such as Thread.sleep().

Comment: Is checking the time before and after good enough ?

Comment: Why do you want to test that Thread.sleep is working? Do you not trust the JVM programmers? I would focus on testing your own code, and trust the people working on the JVM to have tested basic things like Thread.sleep already.

Comment: I concur: why do you want to test it? If you want to test methods that just happen to contain Thread.sleep, I think the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868637/testing-with-thread-sleep is the way to go (assuming you can re-factor the code you test)

Comment: @vegaasen can you please add a code snippet which shows me how I could do that ? It would be of great help .

Comment: @SergGr    I want to test if the sleep part is actually happening or not. Like I would like to know like if there could be like a visual indication on how I could achieve the testing part of "Thread.sleep"

Comment: As yshavit said, you can trust JVM-developers that Thread.sleep does work (unless you do something very-very hacky). Do you have specific reasons not to trust JVM?

Comment: Its not that i dont trust the JVM developers. I need some sort of indication that im getting a sleep of one second after every 50 iterations( in my code). So i would like to know if there could be some appropriate way of doing it. Like can there be like total time taken sort of a thing ? which shows how long the for loop actually runs?

Comment: @vegaasen He is an absolutely newbie. So please please please: never ever tell a newbie to use PowerMock. When writing your **own** code, then simply write **testable** code that avoids static calls; and then your need to PowerMock vanishes. PowerMock should not be used, if at all when you have to test 3rd party code that you can't rework to become testable.

Comment: so I dont need to add any test for indication of sleep working or not right ?

Comment: @tourani123 you don't need to test for it working correctly, you should test that you are *calling it* correctly. Apart from the fact that your JVM is going to be in a really bad way if `Thread.sleep` isn't working correctly, `Thread.sleep` isn't part of your system under test: a unit test should test the unit of code. `Thread.sleep` isn't part of your code, so this unit test shouldn't test it.

Comment: @GhostCat, thats true, however - as this example included an implicit Thread.sleep(), which indeed poses a bad practise/architecture - using PowerMock solves the issue regarding testing that the static method were indeed invoked. Solving the baseline/"actual issue" is another story. I just answered what would help with the provided example - if the actual implementation is good or not is not of my comments concern :-P :)

Comment: @GhostCat I disagree. If the question is "how do I use the dangerous chainsaw to do X", then you can describe how to use the dangerous chainsaw; but if the question is "how do I do X", and there are better alternatives to the chainsaw that you, as a competent butcher, would choose to use, don't even mention the chainsaw.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm disagreeing that "it is not of your concern when he uses the chainsaw to cut into his leg", especially if a) you were the one that first mentioned the chainsaw; b) you don't make it very clear that you wouldn't use the chainsaw yourself.

Comment: @vegaasen Yeah well, that is like you are the chef in the kitchen; and your newbie apprentice asks you "how to cut the bones in that piece of meat"; and you tell him: "go use the dangerous chainsaw over there"; instead of telling him "dont do that; better cut around". But right, this is different: it is not of your concern when he uses the chainsaw to cut into his leg ;-) ... and to avoid any misunderstanding: using PowerMock here is the *wrong* approach. Don't do that.

Comment: @AndyTurner OK, got that and "reworded" my comment.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `Sleeper` interface:

```
interface Sleeper {
  void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

And then inject an instance of this, either into the method as a parameter, or as a constructor parameter. Then call in place of `Thread.sleep`.

For testing, you can then simply pass in a mock, and check that it is called the expected number of times. This is all you should be testing: it is safe to assume that the `Thread.sleep` method works; you just need to make sure you are using it in the way you expect.

This of course allows your test to run a lot faster too (if you want), because your mock does not have to wait for "real" sleeps.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet please?

Comment: @tourani123 Seriously: he told you **all** the things you need to get started. You don't learn by other people doing things for you. You learn by doing things yourself.